# Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\principal.php on line 45

Tags: php, mysql, session, undefined, cuenta-usuario

```
    ?php
    session_start();
    require 'conexion.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
       header("location:index.php?action=login");
    }
```

#sé que acá van las declaraciones `$nombre = $_SESSION['nombre']` y los demás campos de la tabla en heidi, pero no me las toma y me salta el error

Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\principal.php on line 45 cuando hago el `echo "$_SESSION['nombre'];`

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para iniciar sesión, porque en ese solo estás verificando. Aparte, en este código verificas `$_SESSION['usuario']` y el mensaje de error es porque intentas acceder a `$_SESSION['nombre']`

Comment: Haz un var_dump de session.
Ahi podes ver su contenido y ver si trae el "csmpo" nombre o no.